# Regular Expression to find negative numbers without decimal point

Tags: regex, pcre

I have string, for example `-15`. I need find only `-XX` (where `X` is a digit), example `-15` or `-19` without a decimal point (`-19.5`, etc.).

I tried this:

```
\b-\d{2}\b(?!\.\d)
```

And this:

```
\b\-\d{2}\b(?!\.\d)
```

But they do nothing. How do I make a Regular Expression to do this?

Comment: Remove the first `\b`

Comment: Well that is what happens when someone doesn't explain their answer properly, ...

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use a regular expression for this, instead of just using ceil(), etc?

Comment: @Rizier123: The floor is yours :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well I'm not here to clean up the garbage from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this RegEx:

```
-\d{2}(?!\.\d)\b
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xU2hF4/1)</kbd>

There were 2 reasons your one was not working.

First, you needed to remove the very first `\b`.

Secondly, you needed to move the second `\b` after the negative lookahead. Otherwise it was finding the word boundary, then trying to find a `.` and digits. You want it to find the `.` and digits with the word boundary after it, not before.

Comment: And one more question.
I have regex
(\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\b) for this - "8.50 or 22.20"

but my regex return me that string to... "10.0/75"

how can I avoid it?

Comment: No Problem! Yes, [`(\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(?!.\d))`](https://regex101.com/r/dW4rG1/1) works fine. You can use [Regex101](https://regex101.com) to test your RegEx